# How should I build a list of items that link to different controller actions?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC web app and on one page I wish to show a table of items which will include a link to the detail for that item.  Pretty basic.  However, the items I wish to display in the list are all subclasses of a common base type and so the links need to reference different controller actions.

So, my question is: where/how should I construct those links (see example below)?

I can achieve my goal already in a number of ways (e.g. construct route while mapping business object to view model, use flags or magic strings in the view model, have a single 'base' controller action that selects the appropriate view, etc.) but none seem particularly 'clean' so this is more a question about best practice than mechanics.

By way of example, suppose my 'Assignments' table looks like:

```
Id   <OtherCommonFields>  Type    Name           Link
1    <some data>          Event   Some event     /event/1
4    <some data>          Task    Some task      /task/4
3    <some data>          Event   Another event  /event/3
2    <some data>          Task    Another task   /task/2
5    <some data>          Event   One more event /event/5
```

Where 'Tasks' and 'Events' are both subclasses of 'Assignment'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the short version i would say is to create a new actionlink extension method called AssignmentLink, where you pass in the id and the type.

inside the assignmentlink method, do a switch on the type and return the correct url in the form of an actionlink.
that way if you add different kinds of assignments or whatever, you control everything in one central helper.

in a previous mvc app, hyperlinks caused us a lot of headaches. when we renamed a controller, or moved a controller to a new area etc, updating all the references to that controller took forever. so in our most recent project we wrapped up all hyperlink logic into an object called "linkdata"

we then created extensions for our linkdata object, with any logic in the helper or extensions.

http://codingsmith.co.za/extending-the-actionlink-helper-in-mvc/ if you're interested, but you can get away with far less in your example, just a simple extension will do it.